# Redirect stdout and stderr to separate screens with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, console

In ubuntu, How to dedirect stdout and stderr to separate screens with dual monitors?

Comment: Do you want to do this on a command-line-only system, redirecting to different text-based virtual consoles displayed on two different monitors? Or is it sufficient to have two Terminal windows, one on one monitor and one on the other, run the command in one of them, and redirect `stderr` (or `stdout`) so it appears on the other?

Comment: command-line-only system, with 2 monitors

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### With terminals in desktop Ubuntu

- Open a terminal and move it to the second monitor.
- Type `tty` in that terminal, and you will get a response of the form `/dev/pts/N`, where N is a number (1, 2, ....)
- Open another terminal on the first monitor. This is where you will run your commands
- To redirect `stderr` to the other terminal:

  `command 2>/dev/pts/N`
- e.g. try `ls /askubuntu 2>dev/pts/N` and you should see `ls: cannot access /askubuntu: No such file or directory` on the second terminal.
- Replace 2 with 1 to redirect `stdout` instead.

This **should** work similarly for virtual consoles on a command-line system, with `/dev/pts/N` replaced by `/dev/ttyN`but I haven't tested it. Pseudo-TTYs (e.g. ssh sessions) still use the `/dev/pts/N` syntax.

Comment: The answer for desktop is fine